# How to improce the performance of this algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have the following algorithm:
I have a graph and a related I have a topological sorting (In graph theory, "a topological sort or topological ordering of a directed graph is a linear ordering of its vertices such that for every directed edge uv from vertex u to vertex v, u comes before v in the ordering. ").
Given a `start_position` and an `end_position` (different from the start_one), I want to verify if shifting the element of the list that is at `start_position` to the `end_position` preserves the topological order, i.e, if after the shifting i still have a topological order.

There are two cases : left_shift (if `start_position` > `end_position`) and right_shift (otherwise).

[image]
[image]

Here is my attempt:

```py
def verify(from_position:int, to_position:int, node_list:List[str], instance:pb.Problem):
    if from_position < to_position :
        #right-shift
        for task_temp in node_list[from_position+1:to_position+1]:
            if (node_list[from_position],task_temp) in instance.all_predecessors:
                return False
        return True

    if  to_position < from_position :
        #end_shift
        for task_temp in node_list[to_position:from_position]:
            if (task_temp, node_list[from_position]) in instance.all_predecessors:
                return False
        return True
```

PS: `all_predecessors` are a set of tuples (2 elements) that has all the edges of the graph.

Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: "I want to verify if shifting the element of the list that is at start_position to the end_position" -- what does this mean?

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry i forgot to continue the sentence. I want to verify if shifting the element of the list that is at ```start_position``` to the ```end_position``` preserves the topological order, i.e, if after the shifting i still have a topological order.

Comment: Can you explain what "topological order" is?

Comment: @Nathan "a topological sort or topological ordering of a directed graph is a linear ordering of its vertices such that for every directed edge uv from vertex u to vertex v, u comes before v in the ordering. "

Comment: From given info, the algo looks fair to me. But is there other way to check edges other than iterating tro `all_predecessors`?

Comment: If your algo’s gonna check against multiple cases, then it’s worth moving the in/out relationships onto the node. You run thro `all_predecessors` once, and for each tuple `(A, B)`, you do `A.out.append(B)`, `B.in.append(A)`. Then when verifying, you check against `movedNode.in` or `.out`, should be way less iterations.

Comment: @hackape is this better than the enswer by sneffel ?

Comment: Yeah I believe so.

Comment: You see, sneffel’s solution is to iterate thro the whole list, whilst track them with a growing set (keeps adding in nodes that we encounter), then for each node we check if every `node.in` element presents in that set.

Comment: Your original solution, combined with my suggestion, would be to iterate thro just a slice of the list, then check if the `moved_node` presents in each node’s `.in` or `.out`, depending on left or right shift. It’s quite obvious your original approach is better, just needs a bit enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach is asymptotically optimal: Just run through the (new) ordering and verify that it satisfies the topological criteria. You can do this by maintaining a bitfield of the nodes encountered so far, and check that each new node’s predecessors are set in the bitfield. This takes linear time in the number of nodes and edges, which any correct algorithm will need in the worst case.

For other variants of the problem (e.g. measuring in the size of the shift, or optimizing per-query time after preprocessing) there might be  better approaches.

Comment: No, but let me know if anything in my answer is ambiguous.

Comment: first, do you think that this is better than the  answer in the comment of  @hackape?

Comment: Converting the graph representation to an adjacency list, as that comment suggests, is required for the method I described.

Comment: I am a little bit confused, I can't see the difference between your approach and his comment (take a look at see his comments)